Is Stack Exchange's Imgur now working in China? [A: it's probably a temporary thing]
Wow!  I can see this Stack Exchange Imgur image (from this Q) from within China (no VPN, proxy, etc.):

It looks like this was temporary---sometimes blocked sites temporarily work.  I now cannot images to download.
While there's still no ping response from imgur.com:
becky@becky-Inspiron-5379:~$ ping imgur.com
PING imgur.com (31.13.69.160) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- imgur.com ping statistics ---
27 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 26614ms

Ping response from i.stack.imgur.com:
becky@becky-Inspiron-5379:~$ ping i.stack.imgur.com
PING i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net (104.16.2.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.16.2.35 (104.16.2.35): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=560 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.2.35 (104.16.2.35): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=890 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.2.35 (104.16.2.35): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=506 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.2.35 (104.16.2.35): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=733 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.2.35 (104.16.2.35): icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=962 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.2.35 (104.16.2.35): icmp_seq=6 ttl=50 time=577 ms


Let's verify...
ViewDNS.info:

Chinese firewall test results for i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net ...
All servers were able to reach your site. This means that your site should be accessible from within mainland China.


(Related Q: If I wanted to include a picture and have it be visible when in China, what are my options?)

Websites blocked in mainland China

69 | Imgur | imgur.com | imgur.com | Image Sharing | English | 2019, March to present | Blocked 


Test if a site is blocked in China

Beijing - imgur.com Not Working in China
  Shenzhen - imgur.com Not Working in China
  Inner Mongolia - imgur.com Not Working in China
  Heilongjiang Province - imgur.com Not Working in China
  Yunnan Province - imgur.com Not Working in China
  This URL appears to be blocked in China.

Yeah, it's blocked.

Apparently you can play with your hosts file and get around it though: How do I access a banned Imgur site?

I was rather excited for a short while (:
